# Organize Runtime into modules

Tags: runtime, macro

In the examples I've seen so far I can see that all the `[pallet::*]` definitions are within the `#[frame_support::pallet]` module.

Is there any way we can split these into separate modules? For example would it be possible to create a `storage.rs` module and add the storages there like so

```
#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type TotalSupply<T: crate::Config> = StorageValue<_, u64, ValueQuery>;
```

The issue I'm facing is that I can't seem to find how to import the `pallet::storage` macro.

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do a bit more concretely and why?

Comment: @DanShields I think he wants to have a file (not lib.rs) where he can put all the `#[pallet::storage]` definitions. I think its not possible, or at least I was not able to do so, but sometimes you can have a lot of `storage` items, so it would be nice to move everything that is not an extrinsic outside of the lib.rs

Comment: Exactly what @andresvsm wrote. Basically have more flexibility in terms of how you want to structure your code base.

Comment: @ppoliani Although my lib.rs file is quite big, I have moved out auxiliar functions (the ones that are not under `#[pallet::call]`), custom data structures, custom enums and of course, tests, mocks and benchmarks. But I'm not sure you can remove things that are declared within the `pub mod pallet {...}` scope

Comment: @andresvsm that's cool. I did the same exact thing as well

Answer (score 2):

```
For example would it be possible to create a storage.rs module and add the storages there like so
```

I think the answer is no. You can't split #[pallet::storage] from pallet module. When you go into the #[frame_support::pallet] macro's expand process, you'll see components in pallet are expanded as the whole.

The source code of expand pallet can be found [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f39769740858bf480ef13adbfd46267afce92eb9/frame/support/procedural/src/lib.rs#L406).